# How to correctly use Solver() command in Python API of Z3 with declared function

Tags: python, z3

I'm getting unexpected results with some script using Python API of Z3. I think that I'm misunderstanding some process or simply using some command wrong. For example, suppose I have the following script:

```
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')

def g(x):
    if x == 0:
       return 1
    elif x > 0:
       return x**(x+1)

s = Solver()
s.add(g(x) > x)
print s.check()
if s.check()== sat:
    m = s.model()
    m.evaluate(x, model_completion=True)
    print m
```

This will return the following output:

```
sat
[x = 0]
```

That it's OK, but if I substitute `s.add(g(x) > x)` by `s.add(x > 1, g(x) > x)`, this returns `unsat`. I was expecting something like:

```
sat
[x = 2]
```

Can anybody help me to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's if-then-else does not translate to Z3's if-then-else. You have to use the "If" function. See here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3.py#L1092

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, function g should be defined as: `return If(x==0, 1, x*(x+1))`. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes. Note that your original example used `**` and your suggested replacement only has `*`, the first of which is exponentiation, and the latter is multiplication. Make sure you pick the one you want! (I wouldn't be surprised if Z3 started answering `unknown` in the presence of exponentiation, however. But that's not what we're discussing anyhow.)

Comment: Yep! You're right. This was a typo. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

My Python skills are slightly underdeveloped, but I think the crucial concept underlying this problem is that Python functions do not translate to Z3 functions, e.g., `if x == 0: ...` will not create a Z3 function that checks all possible values of `x`. The easiest way to check is to just print the solver, so that it will show you the constraints, just add `print s`. In your unsatisfiable case, I get `[x > 1, x < 1]`, which is indeed unsatisfiable.

Comment: Oh! I see. This makes things much more clear. Thank you!